# AngularJs $http sends date object to server without time offset

Tags: c#, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datetime

I have an AngularJs app, one of the pages has bootstrap datetime picker tool.
and this is what the input which is using it looks like:

```
<input class="form-control"
   is-open="vm.search.openFromYear"
   name="txtfromYear"
   ng-click="vm.search.openFromYear = !vm.search.openFromYear"
   ng-init="vm.search.openFromYear = false"
   ng-model="vm.searchModel.fromYear"
   placeholder="dd/MM/yyyy"
   show-button-bar="false"
   type="text"
   uib-datepicker-popup="dd/MM/yyyy" />
```

When I choose a date I see it correctly in the input, let's say I choosed `14/01/2017`..

In `vm.searchModel.fromYear` it's saved as js date object, with the date value and timezone `Sun Jan 14 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (Turkey Standard Time)`.

The problem is when I send this to server it's converted by `$http` service and sent by ajax like: `2018-01-13T21:00:00.000Z`.

As you see it's one day behind (because of converting to `UTC` format, but without the time offset +3 hours.

The API receives this string and bind it to a property of `DateTime` type but as it is, the date will be `2018-01-13`, not `2018-01-14` as the user really choose it.

Any idea why is that happening ?  I read some answers and didn't find an explanation or a solution.

Comment: Your back end isn't accounting for UTC. Nothing wrong with the front end

Comment: Look at what `console.log(new Date('2018-01-13T21:00:00.000Z'))` displays

Comment: On client it'll be displayed correctly because browser takes into consideration the timezone, but on server it doesn't know the offset at all since it's not mentioned in the date string value that sent to it.

Comment: Yes it is. `Z` is zulu which means it is GMT

Comment: Right, but the client is +3 hours ahead from GMT, I can't see +3 value in the string sent to server, am I missing something ?

Comment: Makes no difference if you store UTC date. Will convert back to whatever timezone client uses. Server itself could be in a different timezone also

Comment: I'm using this value to search for values, the date should be on the client the same as in server: `2018-01-14` not `2018-01-13`

Comment: So take the provided ISO string and get the UTC date from it server side and store that

Answer (score 0):

the ISO string that $http converts is correct. since you just need an explanation:

time is 21:00 in a GMT zone at the time of 00:00 in a GMT+3 timezone. the ISO string represents the GMT zone time which is 3 hours behind the GMT+3 hence the date

Comment: How the server (which is receiving '2018-01-13T21:00:00.000Z' value) will know if the offset is +3 or +5 or any other value ?

Comment: i suggest you convert the client date to the timezone of server before sending to server. i.e define the server's timezone in client's app config. [moment](http://momentjs.com) and [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/) would help.